# Attempt to read property "id" on null Laravel 8 eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query that fetches comments of posts. It returns this error when a particular post has no comments. Below is my query.

```
$comments=PostComments::with('user:id,username')
            ->where('post_id',$this->id)->latest()->get();
```

This is my Comments model

```
    protected $table = "post_comments";
    protected $fillable = ['comment','post_id','user_id'];
    protected $hidden = ["updated_at","laravel_through_key","post_id"];
    // Carbon instance fields
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'id','user_id')->latest();
```

Comment: probably that `$this` is null, therefore you can not get `id`. Can you show how you try and get the id?

Comment: also you should fix the relation `return $this->belongsTo(User::class);` .

Comment: The `$this->id` is gotten from the post resource class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$this` must be null. You could show a screenshot of the error where it will show you the line where the error occurred, which would make debugging it easier.